# STM32WB55 connection to SD card with SPI FR_NOT_READY

Tags: stm32, spi, sd, nucleo, filesystem

I am very new at this and I don't understand a lot, so please be patient.

I have an STM32WB55 to which I need to connect an SD module to store data from some sensors in SPI mode. I basically followed some tutorials and got to the conclusion that fatfs is the way to go.

So, after debugging it step by step I can mount the card, but it does not let me to open it. I always get FR_NOT_READY. I suppose that this comes from the user_diskio.c and then from fatfs_sd.c where I have my SD_disk_status function.

I followed and read all the tutorials on line that I could put my hands on and it is still not working whatever I may do. I suspect that my problem lies within the clock that I need to program. (I don't understand it AT ALL). The guys in the video set one clock to HSE and the other to PLLCLK (check the photos). However when I do this, it returns me some 0xffffff8 error or 0x88888 saying "Failed to execute MI command". Is this even possible on this type of microcontroller? Having HSE and PLLCLK together?

This is the tutorial that I am focusing the most on: https://controllerstech.com/sd-card-using-spi-in-stm32/

Here's my code, the clock and my return of FR_NOT_READY.

I am sorry if all of these are stupid questions, but I am so lost and I have no clue what to do, as I literally read everything I could find, and it either didn't help much or I didn't understand it enough in order for it to be helpful.

```
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

FATFS fs; //file system
FIL fil; // file
FRESULT fresult; //to store the result
FATFS *pfs;

/* USER CODE END 0 */




/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */


fresult = f_mount(&fs, "/", 0); //here is either 1 or 0, not sure. on the video it was 0, on the internet it was 1


/****************************** PUTS and GETS ************************************************/

//THIS CREATES THE FILE OR IT OPENS IT IF IT WASN'T ALREADY CREATED
fresult = f_open(&fil, "file1.txt", FA_OPEN_ALWAYS | FA_READ | FA_WRITE);

//WRITING TEXT TO THE FILE
fresult = f_puts("TEXT HERE FOR THE FILE", &fil);
/* Close file */
f_close(&fil);

/* Close file */
f_close(&fil);
// 
/* USER CODE END 2 *
```

I am also adding the code that I think is returning the FR_NOT_READY:

```
  return STA_NOINIT;  

  /* SD카드 미삽입 */
  if(Stat & STA_NODISK)
    return Stat;        

  /* SD카드 Power On */
  SD_PowerOn();         

  /* SPI 통신을 위해 Chip Select */
  SELECT();             

  /* SD카드 타입변수 초기화 */
  type = 0;

  /* Idle 상태 진입 */
  if (SD_SendCmd(CMD0, 0) == 1) 
  { 
    /* 타이머 1초 설정 */
    Timer1 = 100;

    /* SD 인터페이스 동작 조건 확인 */
    if (SD_SendCmd(CMD8, 0x1AA) == 1) 
    { 
      /* SDC Ver2+ */
      for (n = 0; n < 4; n++)
      {
        ocr[n] = SPI_RxByte();
      }

      if (ocr[2] == 0x01 && ocr[3] == 0xAA) 
      { 
        /* 2.7-3.6V 전압범위 동작 */
        do {
          if (SD_SendCmd(CMD55, 0) <= 1 && SD_SendCmd(CMD41, 1UL << 30) == 0)
            break; /* ACMD41 with HCS bit */
        } while (Timer1);

        if (Timer1 && SD_SendCmd(CMD58, 0) == 0) 
        { 
          /* Check CCS bit */
          for (n = 0; n < 4; n++)
          {
            ocr[n] = SPI_RxByte();
          }

          type = (ocr[0] & 0x40) ? 6 : 2;
        }
      }
    } 
    else 
    { 
      /* SDC Ver1 or MMC */
      type = (SD_SendCmd(CMD55, 0) <= 1 && SD_SendCmd(CMD41, 0) <= 1) ? 2 : 1; /* SDC : MMC */

      do {
        if (type == 2) 
        {
          if (SD_SendCmd(CMD55, 0) <= 1 && SD_SendCmd(CMD41, 0) == 0)
            break; /* ACMD41 */
        } 
        else 
        {
          if (SD_SendCmd(CMD1, 0) == 0)
            break; /* CMD1 */
        }
      } while (Timer1);

      if (!Timer1 || SD_SendCmd(CMD16, 512) != 0) 
      {
        /* 블럭 길이 선택 */
        type = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  CardType = type;

  DESELECT();

  SPI_RxByte(); /* Idle 상태 전환 (Release DO) */

  if (type) 
  {
    /* Clear STA_NOINIT */
    Stat &= ~STA_NOINIT; 
  }
  else
  {
    /* Initialization failed */
    SD_PowerOff();
  }

  return Stat;
}

/* 디스크 상태 확인 */
DSTATUS SD_disk_status(BYTE drv) 
{
  if (drv)
    return STA_NOINIT; 

  return Stat;
}

/* 섹터 읽기 */
DRESULT SD_disk_read(BYTE pdrv, BYTE* buff, DWORD sector, UINT count) 
{
  if (pdrv || !count)
    return RES_PARERR;

  if (Stat & STA_NOINIT)
    return RES_NOTRDY;

  if (!(CardType & 4))
    sector *= 512;      /* 지정 sector를 Byte addressing 단위로 변경 */

  SELECT();

  if (count == 1) 
  { 
    /* 싱글 블록 읽기 */
    if ((SD_SendCmd(CMD17, sector) == 0) && SD_RxDataBlock(buff, 512))
      count = 0;
  } 
  else 
  { 
    /* 다중 블록 읽기 */
    if (SD_SendCmd(CMD18, sector) == 0) 
    {       
      do {
        if (!SD_RxDataBlock(buff, 512))
          break;

        buff += 512;
      } while (--count);

      /* STOP_TRANSMISSION, 모든 블럭을 다 읽은 후, 전송 중지 요청 */
      SD_SendCmd(CMD12, 0); 
    }
  }

  DESELECT();
  SPI_RxByte(); /* Idle 상태(Release DO) */

  return count ? RES_ERROR : RES_OK;
}

/* 섹터 쓰기 */
#if _READONLY == 0
DRESULT SD_disk_write(BYTE pdrv, const BYTE* buff, DWORD sector, UINT count) 
{
  if (pdrv || !count)
    return RES_PARERR;

  if (Stat & STA_NOINIT)
    return RES_NOTRDY;

  if (Stat & STA_PROTECT)
    return RES_WRPRT;

  if (!(CardType & 4))
    sector *= 512; /* 지정 sector를 Byte addressing 단위로 변경 */

  SELECT();

  if (count == 1) 
  { 
    /* 싱글 블록 쓰기 */
    if ((SD_SendCmd(CMD24, sector) == 0) && SD_TxDataBlock(buff, 0xFE))
      count = 0;
  } 
  else 
  { 
    /* 다중 블록 쓰기 */
    if (CardType & 2) 
    {
      SD_SendCmd(CMD55, 0);
      SD_SendCmd(CMD23, count); /* ACMD23 */
    }

    if (SD_SendCmd(CMD25, sector) == 0) 
    {       
      do {
        if(!SD_TxDataBlock(buff, 0xFC))
          break;

        buff += 512;
      } while (--count);

      if(!SD_TxDataBlock(0, 0xFD))
      {        
        count = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  DESELECT();
  SPI_RxByte();

  return count ? RES_ERROR : RES_OK;
}
#endif /* _READONLY */

/* 기타 함수 */
DRESULT SD_disk_ioctl(BYTE drv, BYTE ctrl, void *buff) 
{
  DRESULT res;
  BYTE n, csd[16], *ptr = buff;
  WORD csize;

  if (drv)
    return RES_PARERR;

  res = RES_ERROR;

  if (ctrl == CTRL_POWER) 
  {
    switch (*ptr) 
    {
    case 0:
      if (SD_CheckPower())
        SD_PowerOff();          /* Power Off */
      res = RES_OK;
      break;
    case 1:
      SD_PowerOn();             /* Power On */
      res = RES_OK;
      break;
    case 2:
      *(ptr + 1) = (BYTE) SD_CheckPower();
      res = RES_OK;             /* Power Check */
      break;
    default:
      res = RES_PARERR;
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    if (Stat & STA_NOINIT)
      return RES_NOTRDY;

    SELECT();

    switch (ctrl) 
    {
    case GET_SECTOR_COUNT: 
      /* SD카드 내 Sector의 개수 (DWORD) */
      if ((SD_SendCmd(CMD9, 0) == 0) && SD_RxDataBlock(csd, 16)) 
      {
        if ((csd[0] >> 6) == 1) 
        { 
          /* SDC ver 2.00 */
          csize = csd[9] + ((WORD) csd[8] << 8) + 1;
          *(DWORD*) buff = (DWORD) csize << 10;
        } 
        else 
        { 
          /* MMC or SDC ver 1.XX */
          n = (csd[5] & 15) + ((csd[10] & 128) >> 7) + ((csd[9] & 3) << 1) + 2;
          csize = (csd[8] >> 6) + ((WORD) csd[7] << 2) + ((WORD) (csd[6] & 3) << 10) + 1;
          *(DWORD*) buff = (DWORD) csize << (n - 9);
        }

        res = RES_OK;
      }
      break;

    case GET_SECTOR_SIZE: 
      /* 섹터의 단위 크기 (WORD) */
      *(WORD*) buff = 512;
      res = RES_OK;
      break;

    case CTRL_SYNC: 
      /* 쓰기 동기화 */
      if (SD_ReadyWait() == 0xFF)
        res = RES_OK;
      break;

    case MMC_GET_CSD: 
      /* CSD 정보 수신 (16 bytes) */
      if (SD_SendCmd(CMD9, 0) == 0 && SD_RxDataBlock(ptr, 16))
        res = RES_OK;
      break;

    case MMC_GET_CID: 

      if (SD_SendCmd(CMD10, 0) == 0 && SD_RxDataBlock(ptr, 16))
        res = RES_OK;
      break;

    case MMC_GET_OCR: 
      /* OCR 정보 수신 (4 bytes) */
      if (SD_SendCmd(CMD58, 0) == 0) 
      {         
        for (n = 0; n < 4; n++)
        {
          *ptr++ = SPI_RxByte();
        }

        res = RES_OK;
      }     

    default:
      res = RES_PARERR;
    }

    DESELECT();
    SPI_RxByte();
  }

  return res;
}
```

This is in fatfs_sd.c

And also the code of user_diskio.h where all those functions are called.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
 ******************************************************************************
  * @file    user_diskio.c
  * @brief   This file includes a diskio driver skeleton to be completed by the user.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under Ultimate Liberty license
  * SLA0044, the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with
  * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                             www.st.com/SLA0044
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
 /* USER CODE END Header */

#ifdef USE_OBSOLETE_USER_CODE_SECTION_0
/* 
 * Warning: the user section 0 is no more in use (starting from CubeMx version 4.16.0)
 * To be suppressed in the future. 
 * Kept to ensure backward compatibility with previous CubeMx versions when 
 * migrating projects. 
 * User code previously added there should be copied in the new user sections before 
 * the section contents can be deleted.
 */
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
/* USER CODE END 0 */
#endif

/* USER CODE BEGIN DECL */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include <string.h>
#include "ff_gen_drv.h"

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Disk status */
static volatile DSTATUS Stat = STA_NOINIT;

/* USER CODE END DECL */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
DSTATUS USER_initialize (BYTE pdrv);
DSTATUS USER_status (BYTE pdrv);
DRESULT USER_read (BYTE pdrv, BYTE *buff, DWORD sector, UINT count);
#if _USE_WRITE == 1
  DRESULT USER_write (BYTE pdrv, const BYTE *buff, DWORD sector, UINT count);  
#endif /* _USE_WRITE == 1 */
#if _USE_IOCTL == 1
  DRESULT USER_ioctl (BYTE pdrv, BYTE cmd, void *buff);
#endif /* _USE_IOCTL == 1 */

Diskio_drvTypeDef  USER_Driver =
{
  USER_initialize,
  USER_status,
  USER_read, 
#if  _USE_WRITE
  USER_write,
#endif  /* _USE_WRITE == 1 */  
#if  _USE_IOCTL == 1
  USER_ioctl,
#endif /* _USE_IOCTL == 1 */
};

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
  * @brief  Initializes a Drive
  * @param  pdrv: Physical drive number (0..)
  * @retval DSTATUS: Operation status
  */
DSTATUS USER_initialize (
    BYTE pdrv           /* Physical drive nmuber to identify the drive */
)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN INIT */
    return SD_disk_initialize(pdrv);
  /* USER CODE END INIT */
}

/**
  * @brief  Gets Disk Status 
  * @param  pdrv: Physical drive number (0..)
  * @retval DSTATUS: Operation status
  */
DSTATUS USER_status (
    BYTE pdrv       /* Physical drive number to identify the drive */
)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN STATUS */
    return SD_disk_status(pdrv);
  /* USER CODE END STATUS */
}

/**
  * @brief  Reads Sector(s) 
  * @param  pdrv: Physical drive number (0..)
  * @param  *buff: Data buffer to store read data
  * @param  sector: Sector address (LBA)
  * @param  count: Number of sectors to read (1..128)
  * @retval DRESULT: Operation result
  */
DRESULT USER_read (
    BYTE pdrv,      /* Physical drive nmuber to identify the drive */
    BYTE *buff,     /* Data buffer to store read data */
    DWORD sector,   /* Sector address in LBA */
    UINT count      /* Number of sectors to read */
)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN READ */
    return SD_disk_read(pdrv, buff, sector, count);
  /* USER CODE END READ */
}

/**
  * @brief  Writes Sector(s)  
  * @param  pdrv: Physical drive number (0..)
  * @param  *buff: Data to be written
  * @param  sector: Sector address (LBA)
  * @param  count: Number of sectors to write (1..128)
  * @retval DRESULT: Operation result
  */
#if _USE_WRITE == 1
DRESULT USER_write (
    BYTE pdrv,          /* Physical drive nmuber to identify the drive */
    const BYTE *buff,   /* Data to be written */
    DWORD sector,       /* Sector address in LBA */
    UINT count          /* Number of sectors to write */
)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WRITE */
  /* USER CODE HERE */
    return SD_disk_write(pdrv, buff, sector, count);
  /* USER CODE END WRITE */
}
#endif /* _USE_WRITE == 1 */

/**
  * @brief  I/O control operation  
  * @param  pdrv: Physical drive number (0..)
  * @param  cmd: Control code
  * @param  *buff: Buffer to send/receive control data
  * @retval DRESULT: Operation result
  */
#if _USE_IOCTL == 1
DRESULT USER_ioctl (
    BYTE pdrv,      /* Physical drive nmuber (0..) */
    BYTE cmd,       /* Control code */
    void *buff      /* Buffer to send/receive control data */
)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN IOCTL */
    return SD_disk_ioctl(pdrv, cmd, buff);
  /* USER CODE END IOCTL */
}
#endif /* _USE_IOCTL == 1 */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

This is clock settings part 1:

[image: clock settings part 1]

This is clock settings part 2:

[image: clock settings part 2]

This is the error:

[image: error message]

Comment: You might be a little more specific what works and what does not. It is not clear which function returns FR_NOT_READY.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers! I edited the clock photos. There are two photos because the clock page was too long in order for it to fit in only one.

Comment: FR_NOT_READY is returned after I do my f_open function. I am not so sure where this comes from exactly...